# Trouble inserting data into mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a few string variables I am trying to insert them into my DB but I am having trouble because nothing is being inserted into the DB. I know the variables are populated. Since all variables are string I'm converting some of them to integers because those fields in the db table are type integer. I tried assigning the mysql_query to a variable and then check to return an error but it didn't display anything. I'm a bit new at PHP so I'm not sure what's wrong with my code below. I appreciate the help.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$connect) { die("Could not connect: ". mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db("dbname");

mysql_query($connect,"INSERT INTO table1 (id, AU, TI, JO, VL, ISS, PB, SN, UR, DO, SP, EP, PY) VALUES ('NULL', '".$authors."', '".$title."', '".$journal."', '".(int)$volume."', '".(int)$issue."', '".$publisher."', '".$serial."', '".$url."', '".$doi."', '".(int)$startpage."', '".(int)$endpage."', '".(int)$year."')");

mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: try `echo mysql_error()` and tell us what is it.

Comment: everything seems to be correct with the statement. I think one of the variables are of a bad typo.

Comment: The `'NULL'` should be just `NULL`, but I don't know if that's ultimately the problem. I _would_ recommend using the PDO class (and prepared statements) instead of mysql_* function for interacting with the database.

Comment: > Fatal error: Function name must be a string in public_html/stuff/parse2.php on line 149
(line 149 is where i wrote the echo mysql_error())

Comment: Seems unlikely that it's desirable for Id to be null anyway. PS you should seriously think about better names for your columns, I'd hang your arse out to dry in a code / design review.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it's probably an autoincrement, so passing null just gives the next value

Comment: It does? Is that some PHP or MySql muppetry then?  Shouldn't be in the Insert statement. Or May ID doesn't stand for Id. :(

Comment: column id is primary index, autoincrement of the table

Comment: One simple thing to try is to print the query, and then try it out via phpmyadmin (or commandline mysql).

Comment: @towr how would I be able to print the query for this instance?

Comment: Just do `echo "INSERT INTO table1 (id, AU, TI, JO, VL, ISS, PB, SN, UR, DO, SP, EP, PY) VALUES ('NULL', '".$authors."', '".$title."', '".$journal."', '".(int)$volume."', '".(int)$issue."', '".$publisher."', '".$serial."', '".$url."', '".$doi."', '".(int)$startpage."', '".(int)$endpage."', '".(int)$year."')";` before/instead of the `mysql_query(...);`

Comment: @towr INSERT INTO table1 (id, AU, TI, JO, VL, ISS, PB, SN, UR, DO, SP, EP, PY) VALUES (NULL, 'author1, author2, author3 ', 'Evaluating delta asymmetry', 'journal name ', '58', '2', 'some publisher Ltd ', '1365-3091 ', 'http://dx.doi.org/88888 ', '88888 ', '478', '507', '2011')

Comment: Figured it out... the mysql query is supposed to be
> mysql_query('the query here',$connection)

Mine was flip-flopped. However what do if the variables return a bool(false) value? Will that still be entered into the db?

Comment: Yes, that would still be entered into the database. As empty string or 0 depending on whether it's a string or int.

Comment: All sorted, thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug your code, adding some more useful checks.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect: ". mysql_error());
}

$dbSelected = mysql_select_db("dbname", $link);
if (!$dbSelected) {
    die ("Can't select db: " . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("YOUR_QUERY", $link);
if (!$result) {
    die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
```

ps: you may want to use [mysqly::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), just because [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) is deprecated

ps2: you should google about SQL Injection, since your statement doesn't look secure (unless those values are escaped somewhere)

NOTE: I just noticed that you are using a wrong order for the parameters on mysql_query($query, $link). You have put $link as first parameter.

Comment: It returns Invalid query:  but nothing for the error  
>$insert = mysql_query($connect,"INSERT INTO pubsinfo (id, AU, TI, JO, VL, ISS, PB, SN, UR, DO, SP, EP, PY) VALUES ('NULL', '".$authors."', '".$title."', '".$journal."', '".(int)$volume."', '".(int)$issue."', '".$publisher."', '".$serial."', '".$url."', '".$doi."', '".(int)$startpage."', '".(int)$endpage."', '".(int)$year."')");
if (!$insert) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query($link, $query)`? See the doc, it is  `mysql_query($query, $link)`

Comment: you are right that was one of the problems. Also the other one was some of the variables were returning bool(false) (i sorted this one out already though). Thank you for your help :)